# What is the meaning of New Disk and Existing Disk in GCP Instance Templates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In an Instance Templates for GCP Managed Instance Groups what is the meaning of:

> New disks and
>   Existing disks

that is showed in the Console beside the boot disk? I cannot find any doc to explain that. When I create an Instance Template I can set "Additional Disks" but I am wondering if they have anything to do with them? And if so, how they match?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Adding or Resizing" disks is not an "Instance template" feature, but for Compute Engine capability, you can find this too while "Creating a VM Instance".

New disks and Existing disks:

Add a new disk means to add as a attachment to your VM Instance or Template an empty disk, this will be in blank. 
By the other hand adding a existing disk means you want to attach one you have in your "Disks" menu or it could be one that is in use by another resource.

There are different ways to add this disk depending the type and region/zone:

- [Zonal persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)
- [Regional persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk)
- [Local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd)